# how to pass the variables of lat lan in the .load jquery function

Tags: php, jquery, function, variables

In the below code I am trying to pass the variable lat and lon in the `.load()` but I am unable to pass the the variables

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x=document.getElementById("demo");
    function getLocation() {
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
            x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        var lat=position.coords.latitude;
        var lng=position.coords.longitude;
        $(".content").load("page1.php?lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng);
    }

});
```

how to pass this two variable in the `.load()`?

Comment: have you tried to `console.log(lat, lng)` to see if you're even getting the variables first?

Comment: @ntgCleaner please send the complete code to do this

Comment: I did.  Copy and paste that line at the end of your 'showPosition()' function, then look at your browser console to see if it outputs anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there should work..

```
$(".content").load("page1.php?lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng);
```

Provided that lat and lng actually contain something.

Test to see if they actually contain values.

```
   console.log("Lat : "+lat+" Lng:"+lng);
```

Also in your page1.php file, you obviously have to retrieve them.

```
   <?php if(isset($_GET)){
            $lat = $_GET['lat']; $lng = $_GET['lng'];
         }
```

Also it looks like your showPosition() function takes a position argument, yet you're calling it without one...

```
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
```

in order for lat and lng to actually return anything, you need to pass the position into the showPosition() function.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition(yourPositiionValue));
```

Although I can't help you with that because I don't know where you're getting that position from.

ie.. I don't know what you would pass into it

But ultimately what Im saying is that because showPosition() needs an argument.

```
function showPosition(argument) {
    // These will be empty, if you don't provide said argument
    var lat=argument.coords.latitude; 
    var lng=argument.coords.longitude;
    $(".content").load("page1.php?lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng);
}
```

Without one, lat and lng will alawys be empty, hence will never work

Comment: I only want to know that the my above code is right or I am going in wrong direction thanks for your help

Comment: Well the original question you asked about .load() is right.  How you have it, will definitely pass them to that php page.  So yes, youre in the right direction.  But all Im pointing out is that lat, lng will be empty, unless you pass an argument

Comment: I helped you as much as I could with the code you gave.  Without the actual position argument that you need to pass to showPosition(), theres not much else I can help you with.  Cuz the fact that you're calling showPosition() without an argument is the reason lat and lng are empty and the load isnt working

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer here is the solution of my above problem

```
 (function ($) {
  $.geolocate = function (options) {
     var def = $.Deferred();
     if (navigator.geolocation) {
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(def.resolve, def.reject, options);
     } else {
         def.reject();
     }
     return def.promise();
 };
  })(jQuery);

 $.geolocate().done(function(position){
 var lat = position.coords.latitude; 
 var lng = position.coords.longitude;
 //alert("Lat : "+lat+" Lng:"+lng);
 $(".content").load("page1json.php?lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng);
 });
```